# Is bucket a single memory location or similar to an array of memory locations?

Tags: java, hashtable, equals, hashcode

As when we say that, for 2 unequal objects having same hash code, the objects are stored in same bucket, what does it imply practically ?

Comment: Totally depends on the implementation, but usually a bucket is a linked list containing all the objects that hash to the same bucket.

Comment: For specifically the standard library container `java.util.HashMap` (and `HashSet` which uses `HashMap`, but NOT `Hashtable`) in Java 8 starts with linked lists but if a **bucket exceeds 8 it is changed to a balanced tree**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2 unequal objects having same hash code, the objects are stored in
>   same bucket, what does it imply practically ?

I will explain you this concept with the below `Product` class example:

**Product class:**

```
public class Product {

     private int id;

     public Product(int id) {
        this.id = id;
     }

     //add getters and settes for id

     public boolean equals(Object obj) {
         Product product = (Product)obj;
         if(id == product.getId()) {
             return true;
         }
         return false;
     }

     public int hashcode() {
         return 1;
     }
}
```

**Test class:**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Product> set = new HashSet<>();
        Product p1 = new Product(1);
        Product p2 = new Product(2);
        set.add(p1);
        set.add(p2);
    }
}
```

Assume that you have created two objects `p1` and `p2` for `Product` class and added to `HashSet` as shown above.

As per the contract of the `Product` class, `p1` and `p2` objects are NOT equal because their product ids are different.
Inside the `HashSet`, these `p1` and `p2` objects are stored into different buckets (simply put different memory locations) as per the `hashcode` returned by the `Product` objects.
Because both of your `p1` and `p2` objects are returning the same hashcode (from `hashcode()` method from `Product` class), they both will be saved into the same bucket (memory location).
Likewise, all of your `product` objects (even though the `product` objects are not equal) will be pushed to the same bucket as their hashcode is same.

So then when you try to search the `product` object from the `HashSet` by using `set.contains()`, the object has to be scanned through & found from the whole products (imagine you have stored 10000 objects).

But **when you implement your `hashcode()` properly i.e., returning different hashcodes for unequal `Product` objects, then the `product` objects will be distributed across different buckets** and **retrieval becomes faster** (no need to scan through all objects) i.e, it improves performance significantly.

**The same concept is applicable for all `Hash`* related collection API (HashMap, HashSet, etc..)** methods in Java.

> Is bucket a single memory location or similar to an array of memory
>   locations ?

One Bucket stores multiple object references and each Hash bucket internally uses data structures like `LinkedList` or `TreeMap` to locate the stored objects.

You can look here for more details on the same subject.

Answer (score 1):

When multiple objects fall into the same bucket they are stored as a singly-linked-list in that bucket.

The advantage of a hashtable is that you can calculate what bucket a key goes to in O(1) time.  This means that if there's only one element per bucket your lookup time stays the same no matter how many elements are in the table.  When you have multiple keys in a single bucket, you can't tell which one you are looking for without checking each one.  When you have a bad hash function that puts many elements into the same bucket you lose the advantage of the hashtable and it starts behaving more like a linked list.